# How to write a MathLink function in C that returns nothing

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp

What is the proper way to write a C MathLink function that returns nothing at all?

The following works, but I'm not sure if all this work is actually necessary:

The template file:

```
:Begin:
:Function:      fun
:Pattern:       fun[]
:Arguments:     {}
:ArgumentTypes: {}
:ReturnType:    Manual
:End:
```

The C code:

```c
void fun() {
    MLPutSymbol(stdlink, "Null");
}
```

In short, here I set the return type to `Manual` and explicitly returned `Null`.  Is this all necessary or is there a shorter way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's exactly what you do. You need to send something back to Mathematica, and the symbol Null is the sensible choice.

Comment: Hmm, and here, you were faster..